# Qt3D Skeletal Animation

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

I am trying to convert the KDAB Qt3D QML Example https://github.com/KDAB/qt3d-examples/tree/master/animated-skinned-mesh to C++. I'm having a really hard time since the documentation is basically not useful!

Here is what I've programmed so far:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DRender>
#include <Qt3DExtras>
#include <Qt3DAnimation>
#include <QSkeletonLoader>
#include <QSkeletonMapping>
#include <QDebug>

Qt3DCore::QEntity *createScene()
{
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity;

    Qt3DRender::QMesh *mesh = new Qt3DRender::QMesh(rootEntity);
    mesh->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:/Robot/robot.gltf"));

    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial *meshMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(rootEntity);
    meshMaterial->setDiffuse(QColor(QRgb(0xa69929)));

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *meshEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *meshTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(rootEntity);

    meshEntity->addComponent(mesh);
    meshEntity->addComponent(meshTransform);
    meshEntity->addComponent(meshMaterial);

    auto* animator = new Qt3DAnimation::QClipAnimator(meshEntity);
    auto* clip = new Qt3DAnimation::QAnimationClipLoader(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:/Robot/robot.gltf"), animator);
    animator->setClip(clip);

    Qt3DCore::QSkeletonLoader* skeletonLoader = new Qt3DCore::QSkeletonLoader(meshEntity);
    skeletonLoader->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:/Robot/robot.gltf"));
    skeletonLoader->setCreateJointsEnabled(true);

    Qt3DCore::QArmature *meshArmature = new Qt3DCore::QArmature;
    meshArmature->setSkeleton(skeletonLoader);
    meshEntity->addComponent(meshArmature);

    Qt3DAnimation::QSkeletonMapping* skeletonMapping = new Qt3DAnimation::QSkeletonMapping(meshEntity);
    skeletonMapping->setSkeleton(skeletonLoader);

    Qt3DAnimation::QChannelMapper *m_channelMapper = new Qt3DAnimation::QChannelMapper;
    m_channelMapper->addMapping(skeletonMapping);

    animator->setLoopCount(Qt3DAnimation::QAbstractClipAnimator::Infinite);
    animator->setChannelMapper(m_channelMapper);

    animator->setRunning(true);
    return rootEntity;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow view;

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *scene = createScene();

    Qt3DRender::QCamera *camera = view.camera();
    camera->lens()->setPerspectiveProjection(45.0f, 16.0f/9.0f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    camera->setPosition(QVector3D(0, 0, 40.0f));
    camera->setViewCenter(QVector3D(0, 0, 0));

    Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController *camController = new Qt3DExtras::QOrbitCameraController(scene);
    camController->setLinearSpeed( 50.0f );
    camController->setLookSpeed( 180.0f );
    camController->setCamera(camera);

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(scene);
    Qt3DRender::QPointLight *light = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity);
    light->setColor("white");
    light->setIntensity(1);
    lightEntity->addComponent(light);
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lightEntity);
    lightTransform->setTranslation(camera->position());
    lightEntity->addComponent(lightTransform);

    Qt3DCore::QEntity *lightEntity2 = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(scene);
    Qt3DRender::QPointLight *light2 = new Qt3DRender::QPointLight(lightEntity2);
    light2->setColor("yellow");
    light2->setIntensity(1);
    lightEntity2->addComponent(light2);
    Qt3DCore::QTransform *lightTransform2 = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(lightEntity2);
    lightTransform2->setTranslation(QVector3D(5.0f, 5.0f, -3.0f));
    lightEntity2->addComponent(lightTransform2);

    view.setRootEntity(scene);
    view.defaultFrameGraph()->setClearColor(QColor(QRgb(0x4d4d4f)));
    view.registerAspect(new Qt3DAnimation::QAnimationAspect());
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

It is not throwing any runtime errors, and displays the robot mesh but it is not animating! The mesh is rendered with arms wide spread, to me it looks like the Armature is not applied to the mesh but I have no idea left what I could be doing wrong..... Btw, the QML example is running. Does anyone see a difference to the original QML that could be causing the problem?

EDIT: The file robot.gltf is the original file from the example!

Answer (score 1):

you didn't add the animator to the meshEntity using addComponent